# How to have a default value for ...params function argument?

Tags: actionscript-3, function, parameters, default-value

I have some classes that implement this interface:

```
function execute(entity:Entity, ...params):void;
```

It's ok, however, I'd like to have this:

```
function execute(entity:Entity, ...params = null):void;
```

because, not every class needs params.

It throws a compilation error.

Seems like I cant have a default value for ...params in AS3. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't set a default in the method signature like that, but you might do something in the function body like `params = params || 'defaultVal';`

Comment: I'm not a fan of that solution tbh :p

Comment: Do you need to specify a default of null? I believe it's fine to call a function with ... params without actually passing any extra parameters.

Answer (score 3):

I am not aware of any way to set the default value of `params` to something other than an empty array at the point of declaration, but a work around would be something like:

```
    function exec(entity:Entity, ... extraParams)
    {

        // EDIT: strange that you are getting null, 
        // double check your variable names and if needed you can add:
        if(extraParams == null)
        {
            extraParams = new Array();
        }

        if(extraParams.length == 0) // If none are specified
        {
            // Add default params
            extraParams[0] = "dude";
            extraParams[1] = "man";
        }

        // the rest of the function
    }
```

Comment: Can't access member `length` of a null or undefined argument

Comment: see if my edit helps, I added a null check in the code above. Also ensure that your variable names match in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

```
function exec(entity:Entity, ...params){
    // Set default values if no params passed:
    params = arguments.length > 1
                 ? params
                 : {foo:'defaultFooVal', bar:'defaultBarVal'};
    // ...
}
```